# QWebView find text inside invisible elements

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, qtscript

In my Qt project I'm using the QWebView to load my html table data.

I'm using the [findText](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8-snapshot/qwebview.html#findText) function to find text in the html page.

But, I can't find invisible text...

HTML sample :

```
<table>

  <tr>
    <td> hello </td>
  </tr>

  <!-- invisible data -->
  <tr style="display:none">

    <!-- I want to find this value -->
    <td> hey </td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

Is there a way to find invisible text elements via Qt?

I know that I can evaluate JavaScript function for that..

But still I'm looking for some Qt solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would try to use `QWebFrame::findAllElements()`.

Comment: I made my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `QWebFrame::findAllElements()` function which will perform elements look up by [CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/selector.html#q1) and return all found elements as `QWebElementCollection` regardless of their visibility. From that list you can find the `QWebElement` that correspond to your searching criterion.